# waiting for run Saga middleware

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

i have a problem with redux-saga actually in my configureStore.js i have :

```
sagaMiddleware.run(mysaga);
```

I want a code execute only when my saga returns something

Comment: We're going to need more code in order to help. In the mean time the documentation might be helpful https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga#sagasjs

Comment: Yes, and a clearer explanation would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you said even if you did not say much, the solution you want is actually:

> reduxSagaMiddleware return a task:
>
> ```
> Middleware.run (saga, ... args)
> ```
>
> Dynamically run saga. Can be used to run Sagas only after the applyMiddleware phase.
>
> ... the method returns a Task descriptor.

from [redux-saga](https://redux-saga.github.io/redux-saga/docs/api/index.html#middlewarerunsaga-args)

So you will have a **task.done** that return a **promise** and you can do:

```
task.done.then(() => {
      // this code will be executed only when the saga is finished
});
```